# Splitting String with multiple spaces

Tags: string, scala, split

I want to separate a string containing two words separated by one or more spaces.
But unfortunately it doesn't work as expected, at the end only one string will result.
I read a file that always has two words in a line. It looks like this: "word1 word2".

getData() returns a List[Int, String] whereby the string contains the two words.

As already mentioned, these two words can be separated by one or more spaces.

```
val myMap = getData("MyFile.txt").map{ line => val tempList = line._2.split(" +")
println(line)
println(tempList(0))
(tempList(0), tempList(1).toInt)
  }.toMap
```

Result of the prints:

(13,word1   word2)

word1  word2

Comment: give a example file and the result you want

Comment: The file consists of only two words separated by one or more spaces.
For example:
https://pastebin.com/34qK2RAx
getData() adds an int, but I don't need it at the moment.
Result should be an array, with word1 on index 0 and word2 on index 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: is this what you need?]    is this what you need? it seems nothing wrong!

as show in the picture

```
val a = "word1  world2"
val b = a.split(" +")
println(b(1))
```

Comment: Screenshot as an answer? Not good, hard to read, unable to copy from it.

Comment: code has been added to the answer! thank you for advice!

Answer (score 1):

Is this the answer you need?

```
import scala.io.Source

object Test{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val filename = "C:\\src/com/practice/MyFile.txt"
     val lines = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.mkString
     val contents = lines.split(" +");
     print(contents(1))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I could solve it myself by using .split("\\s+").
Using split(" +") didn't worked.